# form PDE by eliminating the arbitrary constants $f$ and $g$ in:

Tags: derivatives

$$z=x^2f(y)+y^2g(x)$$

Please help , not very sure how to differentiate this with respect to $x$ then $y$

Comment: If you are trying to differentiate $z$ in respect to $y$ and then $x$(or the other way around, doesn't matter), you don't eliminate $g,f$, when taking the derivative in respect of $x$ you look at $f(y)$ as constant and when in respect of $y$ you look at $g(x)$ as constant

Comment: Please use the body of your Question to give a full problem statement, one that Readers can study without referring back to the title.  When the title alone bears the burden of problem statement, confusion is likely.

Comment: $f,g$ are arbitrary *functions*

Answer (score 1):

Take the derivative according to x and consider function of y as constants. You get:

$$z=x^2f(y)+y^2g(x)$$
$$\partial_yz=\partial_y(x^2f(y)+y^2g(x))=x^2f'(y)+2yg(x)$$
$$\partial_xz=\partial_x(x^2f(y)+y^2g(x))=2xf(y)+y^2g'(x)$$
differentiating twice according to x first then according to y
$$\partial_{yx}z=2xf'(y)+2yg'(x)=\partial_{xy}z$$

Comment: Second line middle part: did you mean $\partial_x (x^2f(y)+y^2g(x))$?

Comment: yes @holo I corrected the typo

Comment: I allowed myself to add to the last line, if you think it is harming you can delete it

Comment: You did well it's better now @holo. Thank you...I appreciate it ...